# react-router: router is undefined in version 0.13.3

Tags: reactjs, browserify, react-router

I'm new to React and React Router so I started off with some examples in the documentation. However, I keep getting error messages stating that the Router is undefined. When checking the ReactRouter object, I do not see a Router at all. I'm using browserify to load the react router.

I'm loading the ReactRouter and accessing the Router as follows:

```
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
console.log(ReactRouter.Router); //This is undefined
```

Any ideas why the Router object is undefined in the code example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 0.13.3, the export *is* the router. From [this doc in the 0.13 branch](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13.x/docs/guides/overview.md#with-react-router):

```javascript
var Router = require('react-router'); // or var Router = ReactRouter; in browsers

// ...

var Route = Router.Route;
// ...

var routes = (
  <Route ...>
    ...
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, that seems to work just fine!

Comment: React.run() is not there anymore.